# TEXT Update versus TEXT insert on Informix Dynamic Server

Tags: informix, embedded-sql

I maintain a 3rd party Informix driver that's written with ESQL-style (Informix API) calls.  I'm working on a bug where, for TEXT fields, INSERTs work fine and UPDATEs fail.  Stepping through the code, what I've found is that we're checking our sqlda structure to tell us whether and how to bind, and after the call to sqli_describe_statement, the sqlda.sqld variable contains 2, the correct number of bound parameters for this insert call, and the parameters appear to be set up correctly whereas in the update case, the number returned is 0, with no parameter information (it should be 1, for the one param in:  "UPDATE TESTTAB SET COLNAME = ? WHERE  OTHERCOLNAME =  1 ").

Using the sqlda information, we correctly set up the required locator structure for the INSERT, but we can't for the update because the information isn't there.  If I fake it out in the debugger and run the set-up-the-locator code for the update, it updates fine.

The statement certainly appears correct, and the same variable is being used for the INSERT as the UPDATE bind.  Moreover sqli_prep has no problem with the update.  For the describe, sqsla.code returns different non-negative numbers 4 and 6, representing the different types of statements being described, as documeneted (i.e., not an error code), so there's no obvious problem there.

1. Is there something else I should be checking in the code ahead of this that might cause this weird behavior (other than special case handling for the different queries -- nothing there)
2. Am I missing something fundamental here about how one does UPDATEs on TEXT fields, such as you have to create a locator object, find the row, and click your heels together three times and say "There's no place like IBM?"

So far Google Fu has turned up little in the documentation, but if you know of docs or samples that point the way, that's cool too.

Comment: Which version of IDS?  Which version of ESQL/C (or CSDK)?

Comment: Hi Jonathan,

I'll check when I get back on Monday.  The IDS server is fairly recent, 11.0 or 11.5 ? I believe.  I'm sure the modified ESQL code we're using is using older headers and libraries, but I can always swap in later stuff (probably 3.0 client) if needed.  Yes, the code was written long ago -- early 90's -- and I'll bet it's been quite awhile since the libraries have been changed if they ever were since the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the murky areas of Informix behaviour.  The behaviour of DESCRIBE is supposed to describe *output* parameters (it is a shorthand for DESCRIBE OUTPUT *stmt* INTO ...); to describe the *input* parameters, you would use DESCRIBE INPUT *stmt* INTO ... instead.

However, for various reasons extending back to the dawn of time (well, 1985, anyway), the INSERT statement got a special case exemption and plain DESCRIBE described its *input* parameters - unlike UPDATE or DELETE (or, these days, MERGE).

So, your code was probably written before DESCRIBE INPUT and DESCRIBE OUTPUT became feasible (that was circa 2000±3 years).  In principle, using the directed DESCRIBE statements should fix the issue.  There may be an ONCONFIG parameter to be set to get this behaviour.

I remember being grateful that the feature arrived, but also I remember thinking "Damn, I'm not going to be able to use that for a while - until the old versions without it are all retired".  I think that has basically happened now - IDS 7.31 in particular is now obsolete, and so indeed are the IDS 9.x versions, so all available versions of IDS support the feature.  OnLine 5.20 - a minority interest - still doesn't and won't ever support it.  So, I need to review how to update my programs such as [SQLCMD](http://www.iiug.org/software/) to exploit this.  The code there includes what I call 'vignettes'; they're complete little programs that illustrate how to work with BYTE and TEXT blobs.  You might find UPDBLOB or APPBLOB, for example, of some use.

Comment: Thanks for that.  It points me in a good direction, which is better than the docs have done so far.  I did compile the same update query using ESQL, and instead of having the right behavior, the ESQL program displayed the same bug as was reported against our driver!  I will take a look at the samples you mentioned in SQLCMD -- I found that through an earlier answer (probably yours) to someone else.  I'll also try compiling the the DESCRIBE INPUT statement you mention above in ESQL, take a look at the resulting C code, and apply the trusted shoehorn design pattern.  Thanks very much again.